# Changing just the tags' color in a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I know how to change the color of the entire text in a textarea: `<textarea style="color:green;" onkeyup="this.style.color=(this.value.length>160)?'black':'red';"></textarea>` you can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3rjzta5u/3/ My question is how can I change the color of just the tags using the same idea? I am not good at javascript to make it work. Hope somebody can help. So if someone types `<b>My Story</b>` I want only the tags to be red not the whole thing. Thank you!!

Comment: Show us an example of what you're talking about, some code and preferably a fiddle

Comment: @mickzer I don't have an example. I don't even know where to begin since I've never encountered anything like that or saw anyone doing it. Online search didn't bring up much of anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: a textarea is nothing but text...there is no innerHTMLl you can style in it. You could apply style to html strings for them to render outside the textarea but that would just be visibly as text inside the textarea

Comment: Did you see the example above? I just styled it using a simple javascript. I just need a code that will do the same thing but instead of doing the whole  text it will just selectively do things like `<b></b> <big></big> <blockquote></blockquote>` etc. Here the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rjzta5u/3/

Comment: @VitalSigns  you can't do it, just the same as what you see inside that textarea as html shows the actual tags as text

Answer (score 0):

You need a rich text editor and with the proper CSS applied, you can get to your goal.

Comment: No, I do not want to use it. I'd like to stick to a regular text area. My question is is it even possible to do without changing it to a rich text editor?

Comment: No, its not. you need some kind of editing capabilities

Comment: I know how to change the color of the entire text in a textarea: `<textarea style="color:green;" onkeyup="this.style.color=(this.value.length>160)?'black':'red';"></textarea>` you can see an example here: https://jsfiddle.net/3rjzta5u/3/ My question is how can I change the color of ust the tags using the same idea. I am not good at javascript to make it work. Hope somebody can help.

Comment: You can change the style for the entire textarea but not the tags in it as the content inside the textarea is considered plain text. Set the designMode property on the textarea to ON